# shutdown tomcat 8 and start tomcat 9

Tags: java, tomcat, server, tomcat8, linode

I am new to java. I had tomcat 8 running on the linode server at following location

```
/usr/share/
```

tomcat8, tomcat8-admin, tomcat8-docs, tomcat8-examples are present at this location.
When I browsed localhost:8080, I got "It works" html page with links for tomcat8-docs, tomcat8-examples, and tomcat8-admin. But I was not able to browse any of the given links(404 error was coming).

After that I installed tomcat9 at following location

```
/usr/local/apache-tomcat9
```

it contains a folder named 'webapps' which in turn contains folders docs,examples, host-manager, manager and ROOT.

I want to shut tomcat8 down and use tomcat9 instead. Is there any way for this.

Comment: Yes, there is a way for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can just run `sudo service tomcat8 stop` and `sudo service tomcat9 start`

Comment: tomcat 8 got stopped but tomcat 9 is not starting by your command. It is showing tomcat9.service not found. I started with ./bin/startup.sh command for tomcat 9. It is showing tomcat9 as running in command line.

Comment: if you want command line status after I ran ./bin/startup.sh command. it is below           Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/apache-tomcat9
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/apache-tomcat9
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/local/apache-tomcat9/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/local/apache-tomcat9/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/apache-tomcat9/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started.

Comment: ok, i guess the name of the service is apache-tomcat9, sudo service apache-tomcat9 start/stop should work